# If $X_t$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ for all $t\geq 0$, does $X_{\sigma }$ will be independent of $\mathcal G$ for a stopping time $\sigma $?

Tags: probability, independence

Let $(X_t)$ be such that $X_t$ is independent of a $\sigma -$algebra $\mathcal G$ for all $t$. Let $\sigma $ a stopping time (We can suppose that $\sigma <\infty $ a.s.). Is $X_\sigma $ independent of $\mathcal G$ ? I think it is, but I don't know how to prove it. What I could prove so far is that if $(X_t)$ is continuous, $$\mathbb E[f(X_{\sigma })\boldsymbol 1_A]=\mathbb E[f(X_\sigma )]\mathbb P(A)\tag{1}$$
for all $f$ continuous and bounded, and all $A\in \mathcal G$ using the fact that there is a decreasing sequence $(\sigma _n)$ s.t. $\sigma _n\searrow\sigma $ and $\sigma _n$ taking finitely many value. But I couldn't prove $(1)$ if $f$ is only Borel-measurable or if $(X_t)$ is not continuous.

Can someone tell me if the result is true (at least if $(X_t)$ is continuous), and how to prove $(1)$ for $f$ measurable, but not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Of course we require also that $\sigma$ is independent of $\mathcal G$.

Comment: @GEdgar: If $\sigma $ is a stopping time for $(X_t)$, doesn't it mean that $\{\sigma\leq t\}\in \sigma (X_s\mid s\leq t)$, and thus, since $X_t$ is independant of $\mathcal G$ for all $t$, then so is $\sigma $. This is wrong ?

Comment: You did not say "for $(X_t)$".  So I did not assume that.  I assumed: we are given a stochastic basis $(\mathcal F_t)$ and $X_t$ is adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)$ and $\sigma$ is a stopping time for $(\mathcal F_t)$.

Comment: @joshua does the post below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not true.

*Hint*: Let $(B_t^{(1)}, B_t^{(2)})$ be a two-dimensional Brownian motion starting at $(0,1)$. Let $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $\mathcal{G}_t$ be the filtrations generated by $B^{(1)}$ and $B^{(2)}$, respectively, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}_\infty$ and $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal{G}_\infty$. Set $\sigma = \inf \{ t > 0 \, : \, B_t^{(2)} = 0 \}$. Then, by construction, $B_t^{(1)}$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$.

Can you show $B_\sigma^{(1)}$ is not independent of $\mathcal{G}$?